# Team Foundation Server Source Control - Shared AssemblyVersion.cs file

Tags: tfs

I am aware that Team Foundation Server Source Control does not support the shared file (link) concept of Visual Source Safe.

I currently have a scenario where we link an AssemblyVersion.cs file across multiple projects. This means that in our MSBuild script, we can update the version in one file and have it propagate throughout the projects.

How would I accomplish this with Team Foundation Server Source Control?

My first thought is to create the file in a central location and have each project include that specific file in that specific location (instead of copying it to the local source directory)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can embed the `AssemblyInfo.cs` as a link file.
But look [here](http://jschreuder.bloggingabout.net/2006/11/02/centralizing-assemblyinfo-settings-or-simplify-versioning-of-solutions/), looks like it works:

In our Teambuild, we have a task which updates the AssemblyFileVersion and other attributes.
We use this [Task](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/dfc0ff53-6b72-43ac-8695-9d287f9aa0b2)

Edit:

Actually it works with a multi solution architecture with round about 29 projects and
on TFS 2005 and 2008.
I personally like the second solution cause you don't need to change all projects,
only need to implement in daily/nightly build.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to check "best practice" before embarking on this. Unless I hear any different, I will mark this as answered shortly.